# FAKE build default behind a proxy server does not work

Tags: f#, visual-studio-code, f#-fake

I'm trying to create a F# project in visual studio code using Fake. When I try to build the project Fake returns an error "System.Net.WebException: 407 proxy requires authentication".

Is there any configuration file where I can write proxy related information so fake can download required files?. I have already changed visual studio user configuration adding the keys:

- http.proxy: http://user:password@proxyIp:proxyPort
- http.proxyStrictSSL: false

This is the complete output of the build process:

> Paket.exe 5.100.2 is up to date. Paket version 5.100.2 Last restore is
>   still up to date. Performance:
>    - Runtime: 969 milliseconds Building project with version: LocalBuild Shortened DependencyGraph for Target Build: <== Build    <== Restore
>         <== InstallDotNetCLI
>            <== Clean
>
> The running order is:
>     - Clean
>     - InstallDotNetCLI
>     - Restore
>     - Build Running build with 1 worker Starting Target: Clean  Deleting contents of ./build/ Finished Target: Clean Starting Target:
>   InstallDotNetCLI (==> Clean) dotnet --version
>   C:\Users\VNP32i6\AppData\Local\dotnetcore\dotnet.exe --version
>   Deleting contents of C:\Users\VNP32i6\AppData\Local\dotnetcore
>   Installing
>   'https://dotnetcli.azureedge.net/dotnet/Sdk/2.0.0/dotnet-dev-win-x64.2.0.0.zip'
>   to 'C:\Users\VNP32i6\AppData\Local\Temp\dotnet-dev-win-x64.2.0.0.zip'
>   Installing
>   'https://dotnetcli.blob.core.windows.net/dotnet/Sdk/2.0.0/dotnet-sdk-2.0.0-win-x64.zip'
>   to 'C:\Users\VNP32i6\AppData\Local\Temp\dotnet-sdk-2.0.0-win-x64.zip'
>   Installing
>   'https://download.microsoft.com/download/F/A/A/FAAE9280-F410-458E-8819-279C5A68EDCF/dotnet-sdk-2.0.0-win-x64.zip'
>   to 'C:\Users\VNP32i6\AppData\Local\Temp\dotnet-sdk-2.0.0-win-x64.zip'
>   Running build failed. Error: System.Net.WebException: Error en el
>   servidor remoto: (407) Se requiere autenticaci�n del proxy.    en
>   System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(Uri address, String fileName)    en
>   System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(String address, String fileName)
>   en Fake.DotNetCli.downloadSDK@496(String tempDir, String downloadPath,
>   String archiveFileName) en
>   D:\code\FAKE\src\app\FakeLib\DotNetCLIHelper.fs:l�nea 503    en
>   Fake.DotNetCli.InstallDotNetSDK(String sdkVersion) en
>   D:\code\FAKE\src\app\FakeLib\DotNetCLIHelper.fs:l�nea 533    en
>   FSI_0005.Build.clo@50-2.Invoke(Unit _arg2)    en
>   Fake.TargetHelper.runSingleTarget(TargetTemplate`1 target) en
>   D:\code\FAKE\src\app\FakeLib\TargetHelper.fs:l�nea 626

Thanks.

Comment: What does the FAKE script do? Can you give us some ideas what the Targets are? But this sounds like a NuGet CLI restore issue that I vaguely remember, so can you also tell us what versions of .NET and ideally also NuGet you are using?

Comment: It looks like there's an issue in the Fake repository for this problem. https://github.com/fsharp/FAKE/issues/1660

Comment: Yes, that might be the problem thank's.